# How to fetch facebook post share details with the help of koala gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala

I want to store all details about particular post which includes likes, comments and shares. I am able the fetch likes and comments with following syntax:

```
graph.get_object('/'+post_id+'/likes?limit=10000&format=json')
graph.get_object('/'+post_id+'/comments?limit=10000&format=json')
```

In similar fashion i tried to fetch share details of that particular post

```
graph.get_object('/'+post_id+'/share?limit=10000&format=json')
```

but it returns empty array. But when fire this query:

```
graph.get_object('/'+post_id)
```

its returns lots of data and also says that `"shares"=>{"count"=>26}`

So that particular post has shares but i am not able to fetch share.

Comment: did you figure this out??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i figured out

```
graph.get_object('/'+post_id+'/sharedposts?limit=10000&format=json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at facebook's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/) I'm not sure you can get anymore than the count.

Comment: Can i fetch activity log of facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else finds this like I did - please note that you will need the "read_stream" permission on the Facebook app in order to make this work.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/sharedposts